# WLAN triangulation of mobile devices from WLAN side as a pose to cell phone app

Tags: wifi

Im trying to measure the signal strength of mobile devices from either existing WLAN routers or creating directional antennas. I want to see what specific routers are picking up the top 3-4 signal strengths from a specific mobile device, and use triangulaiton to gather their locaiton. Any ideas of the best route to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether such router exists or not, but can provide you an alternative and convenient way. Wireless channel is symmetric in both direction; this is, if the router transmits signal at 20 dBm and mobile device receives such signal at -30 dBm, the received signal strength at router would be -30 dBm if the mobile phone transmits at 20 dBm (given that environment does not change much). Then simply install WiFi analyzer app on your Android phone and record the signal strength of your normal routers.